# release jar file download from snapshot locatoin

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, snapshot, spring-cloud-dataflow

On spring cloud dataflow getting started page, 
(https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-data-flow-samples-http-cassandra-overview)

It says run command below, but Error 404(Not found). 
wget https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/2.4.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar

as you can see, snapshot location and RELEASE version jar file.

This is not the only case, so I think there could be some reason.

I needs the meaning. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting it. This is indeed a bug in the data flow site configuration.
This is fixed via:https://github.com/spring-io/dataflow.spring.io/issues/228 
I will post an update once the fix is applied to the site.

Thanks again.

Comment: This is fixed at the site: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/manual/ . Thanks